# SQL XML value filtering using variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, variables, xpath

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.
How should I use a SQL variable as a XPath to filter my data?

The XML column has this data for a particular record:

```
<filters>
    <AreaType>Rural</AreaType>
    <Class>Present</Class>
</filters>
```

This works:

```
select *
from tblData
where XMLFilter.value('(/filters[1]/AreaType[1])', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Rural'
```

This doesn't work:

```
declare @Filter as nvarchar(100) = '/filters[1]/AreaType[1]'
select *
from tblData
where XMLFilter.value('sql:variable("@Filter")', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Rural'
```

Apparently the `sql:variable("@Filter")` is not being correctly used by the `value` method as a XPath.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample of you xml and the db vendor you are using (plsql-oracle, mssql-microsof, mysql-oracle)?

Comment: Do you have an error or it just doesn't return anything?